# Excel Formula/Function to Subtract randomly

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm rather new to excel and I want to use excel or perhaps another program to subtract on a fixed amount but randomly.
It is like n1 + n2 + n3 = 300
But I want n1 and n2 and n3 to be different numbers hence not division

Examples
150 + 75 + 75 = 300

or

100 + 100 + 100 = 300

or

50 + 100 + 150 = 300

A function to subtract a fixed amount but random subtraction
I'm still quite confused on how to do this on excel, sorry for my bad English and explaination
Please help.

Comment: Is it always 3 numbers?

Comment: How is this subtraction? You want n random numbers that _sum_ to a fixed amount, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is always 3 numbers:

The first number we use:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,A1)
```

Then the second:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,A1-B1)
```

Then the third is just the remainder:

```
=A1-B1-C1
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In excel you have your numbers in rows and columns
I would enter 100, 100 , 100 in separate columns of the same row and then use this
formula

=(A1+B1+C1).

Meaning row A1 100, row B1 100, row C1 100. The answer should be 300
if you want to subtract just use the minus sign instead of the plus sign:

formula =(A1-B1-C1).

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.  The user wants the three numbers to be random, but that they always sum to a specific number.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=LET(A,RANDBETWEEN(0,300),B,RANDBETWEEN(0,300-A),HSTACK(A,B,300-SUM(A,B)))
```

Or, if no `HSTACK()` available:

```
=LET(A,RANDBETWEEN(0,300),B,RANDBETWEEN(0,300-A),CHOOSE({1,2,3},A,B,300-SUM(A,B)))
```

I'm just unsure if pure mathematically this is as random as can be. Would it be 'more random' if one would list all possible permutation of 1-300 that would add up to 300 and randomly pick a solution from this list?

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this if you want two numbers to always add up to the same value, is to modify each value with the same amount, by adding to one value and subtracting from the other

```
100 = n1 + n2 = (n1+a) + (n1-a)
```

where `a` is any random number.

To extend this to three numbers, you can use two artbitrary numbers `a` and `b` to do this following

```
100 = n1 + n2 + n3 = (n1+a) + (n2-a+b) + (n3-b)
```

The simplified approach to this it to pick completely random `n2` and `n3` and let `n1` pick up the difference

```
100 = (100-n2-n3) + n2 + n3
```

To do this in Excel, use the `=RANDBETWEEN()` function for `n2` and `n3` and then for `n1` just subtract from 100

```
=100 - SUM(n2,n3)
```